# DoneButton is not rendering in 'react-native-app-intro-slider-rerender-on-prop-change'

Tags: react-native

I am trying to make a multiple choice test with a few questions using React Native package 'react-native-app-intro-slider'. The problem was that this package was not rerendering the items when something changes, state for example. I found a similar or refactored package called 'react-native-app-intro-slider-rerender-on-prop-change' that did the same thing but rerendered items on a state change. But the problem is that it does not render the Done button at last slide.

The last package i used was this :

```
import AppIntroSlider from 'react-native-app-intro-slider-rerender-on-prop-change';
```

The render method for the 'MCTContainer' (Multiple Choice Container) class is :

```
render() {
    if (this.state.showRealApp) {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('TopicGroupDetails', { topicGroup: this.state.topicGroup });
        return null;
    } else {
        const questions = this.state.questions;
        return (
            <AppIntroSlider
                renderItem={this._renderItem}
                slides={questions}
                onDone={this._onDone}
                onSkip={this._onDone}
                activeDotStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#039BE5' }}
                showPrevButton
                showNextButton
                showSkipButton
                showDoneButton
                renderPrevButton={this._renderPrevButton}
                renderNextButton={this._renderNextButton}
                renderSkipButton={this._renderSkipButton}
                renderDoneButton={this._renderDoneButton}
            />
        )
    }
}
```

and its renderDoneButton method is like following :

```
_renderDoneButton = () => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.buttonCircle}>
            <Icon
                name="check"
                color="#039BE5"
                size={24}
                style={{ backgroundColor: 'transparent' }}
            />
        </View>
    );
};
```

This is actually the same, exactly the same as I used for the component 'SliderComponent' where I show tutorial introductory text in multiple slides. It renders the 'done' button fine. But the only differenence is that I used package  'react-native-app-intro-slider' there, not  'react-native-app-intro-slider-rerender-on-prop-change'.

Please help me if someone has encountered such a problem. Thanx in advance ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it.
I just added a condition on "renderItem" function of the "AppIntroSlider", that checks whether it is the last slide. If it is it renders a button that calls "AppIntroSlider"-s "_onDone" method that completes the slide show.

```
_renderItem = ({item}) => {
  return(
          {
                        (this.state.isLastSlide) ? 
                        (
                                <TouchableHighlight
                                    onPress={this._onDone}
                                >
                                <View>
                                    <Text>
                                        COMPLETE SLIDE SHOW
                                    </Text>
                                    <Icon
                                        name="check"
                                            color="white"
                                        size={24}
                                    />
                                    </View>
                                </TouchableHighlight>
                        ) :
                        (<View></View>)
        }
   )
}
```